# Using in_set/2 Constraint

Tags: prolog, constraints, sicstus-prolog, clpfd

I am trying to use constrain `X` to not being a value in a list.

From the [SICStus Prolog manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Membership-Constraints.html):

```
?X in_set +FDSet
```

I can't figure out how to convert a list to a FDSet, though.
I have a list of integers `[2,3,8,9]` and I want to constrain the domain of variable `X` to not being in that list. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the [documentation](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/FD-Set-Operations.html#FD-Set-Operations), what about `list_to_fdset/2`? You can translate to an `FDSet`, then build its *complement*, then post `in_set/2`. If your version does not have `list_to_fdset/2`, you can easily convert the list to a normal domain expression, and then post a negated `in/2` constraint. In your example, you would then post:

```
#\ X in {2}\/{3}\/{8}\/{9}
```

and you only have to describe the relation between a list and a domain expression consisting of singletons, which is easy:

```
list_domain([I|Is], Dom) :-
        foldl(integer_domain_, Is, {I}, Dom).

integer_domain_(I, D0, D0 \/ {I}).
```

Example queries:

```
?- list_domain([1,2,3], Dom).
Dom = {1}\/{2}\/{3}.

?- list_domain([1,2,3], Dom), X in Dom.
Dom = {1}\/{2}\/{3},
X in 1..3.
```

Comment: What about: `X in \ ({2}\/{3}\/{8}\/{9})`

Answer (score 0):

I implemented one like here..

```
/** Constraint domain to memebers of a list (of numbers only) **/

domain_list_constraint(_, []) :- !.
domain_list_constraint(DomainVar, List) :- member(E, List),
                                (atom(E)->atom_number(E, I), 
                                DomainVar #= I; 
                                DomainVar #= E).
```

Comment: This is *generate-and-test*, and forfeits the power of constraints. The point of `in/2` is to deterministically state the domain of a variable. Instead of backtracking (with `member/2`), you should deterministically convert the list to a domain expression, and then post a single `in/2` constraint to fully benefit from CLP(FD) constraints.

Comment: hmm,, sounds good!!! i will see if i can implement that way. Thanks for the advice.